# Flutter: How to send audio data/bytedata in WebSocket?

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io

I'm trying to send byte data(which is audio data) using socket IO. but get error

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: TypedDataView(cid: 147)

```dart
      ByteBuffer _buffer = data.buffer;
      ByteData _byteData = _buffer.asByteData();
      _socketIO?.emitWithAck('eventName', [_byteData]);
```